# How to refence a DBGrid from another form

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

I have a mainForm with a DBGrid and I have a second form with a CheckListBox that shows all of the DBGrid columns for the user to choose. I need to reference in Form2 the DBGrid that I have in MainForm.
I would like this second form to handle all of the procedures connected to the dbdgrid columns , so that I can reuse it easily.
That was the idea, but I dod'nt find the way to pass the DBGrid reference.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the question you asked, on your Form2, define a property

```
TForm2 

[...]
private
  FGrid : TDBGrid
public
  property Grid : TDBGrid read FGrid write FGrid;
```

Then, after you've created an instance of TForm2,  just do

```
Form2.Grid := MainForm.DBGrid1;
```

Then, on Form2, you can do anything valid you like to change `Grid` and the changes will be made to MainForm.DBGrid1.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried and it looks it works. Now, in form2, I need to do something when the DBGrid columns in the main form are moved around. In the MainForm I would have used OnColumnMoved ...

Comment: Well, I've answered your original question, so it would be good if you accept it by clicking the green "tick" icon.  For your OnColumMoved event you give Form2 a procedure with the same parameters signature, write your code in it and assign MainForm.DBGrid1's OnColumnMoved to it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible?

The question should rather be ***Is there a better way to achieve what I want?***

- Would it be maintainable if `Form2` worked basically with a control from a different form? What if other forms would also need to hold references to components on other forms?
- How hard would it be in a year to find a bug if controls are used over different forms?
- Would such a solution match to the [SOLID principles](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod)?

Answering these questions should help you to look for a different approach.

You should consider to [separate UI and business logic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127245/how-can-i-separate-the-user-interface-from-the-business-logic-while-still-mainta). A `TDBGrid` seems to be a convenient way to get data from a database into your application but it violates the *Single Responsibility Principle* since it loads and displays data at the same time. Don't use it as a basic data provider inside your application. Perform the SQL queries from a deeper UI independant layer of your software. Store the results in containers and display them in all the ways you want in your different forms.

Comment: I think you are right in principle, but I would'nt know where to start to find a better way. Moreover this is a case where the secondary form displaying the DBGrid columns layout Always go with a DBGrid..